# how to show 403 error in Meteor.js app?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to notify user that the document is exist but user have no rights to see it.

throwing Meteor.Error from publish function does not work.

```
Meteor.publish "projectWithStories", (projectId) ->
  check projectId, String

  project = Projects.findOne projectId

  # return nothing if there is no project with this id
  unless project then return @ready()

  # check if the user has rights
  if documentAuthorOrAddedUser @userId, project
    [
      Projects.find projectId
      Stories.find projectId: projectId
    ]
  else
    @ready()
    # this does not work =//
    # without this i'm getting 'dataNotFound' that is not valid
    throw new Meteor.Error 403, "Not allowed"
```

also i'm using iron router and 'dataNotFound' hook

=============================EDIT================================

Ok, i'm found the solution!

changing last lines of code to this works like a charm

```
  if
     .....
     .....
  else
    @error throw new Meteor.Error(403, "Not allowed")
```